# If $\frac{5x}{2x^2+5x+1}=\frac13$ then the value of $x+\frac{1}{2x}$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\frac{5x}{2x^2+5x+1}=\frac13$ then the value of $x+\frac{1}{2x}$ is

note $5x=1$

$2x^2+5x+1=3$

or
$15x=2x^2+5x+1$

so $2x^2-10x+1$

so $\frac{5+\sqrt{23}}2$ or $\frac{5-\sqrt{23}}2$

Comment: Those are two roots of your equation $2x^ 2-10x+1 = 0$, let's mark them $x_1, x_2$. If you seek the value of $x+\frac{1}{2}x = \frac{3}{2}x$ just multiply solutions by $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @markich: I think that is $x + \dfrac{1}{(2x)}$.

Comment: @TonyK: i guess you are right. jyothika: Perhaps next time put equations in latex forms for more understandable reading.

Comment: yes @markich my comment box is not working .its x+(1/2x) only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps
$$
\frac{5x}{2x^{2}+5x+1}=\frac{1}{3}
$$
$$
15x=2x^{2}+5x+1
$$
$$
10x=2x^{2}+1
$$
What would we get if we divide both sides of the last equation by $2x$?

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

As $x\ne0,$

$$3=\frac{5x}{2x^2+5x+1}=\frac{5/2}{x+5/2+1/2x}$$

$$\iff\frac{x+5/2+1/2x}{5/2}=\frac13$$

Hope you can take it from here

Comment: Good catch, indeed !

Comment: I don't get it still @lab bhattacharjee .i know you converted to x^2+bx+c

Comment: @jyothika, Remove  the denominator $5/2$ from the LHS

Comment: (x+(1/2x))/5/2+1=1/3

Comment: x+(1/2x)=2/15 right?